# A question about the NSP order of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

A matrix $D$ is said to have the NSP order of $\Omega$ if
$$\forall v \neq 0 \text{ with } Dv = 0 \\
\sum_{j \in T} |v_j|< \sum_{j \notin T} |v_j| \text{ for all } T\in \{1, 2, \cdots, M\} \text{ with } \#T \leqslant \Omega
$$

In a research paper, I learned that if any two columns
 of $D$ are a multiple of each other, the NSP has surely violated already for $\Omega = 2$

I don't understand what does it mean the NSP will be violated, does it mean the matrix will not have the NSP of any order if any two columns are correlated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: Say the $j$ 'th column of $D$ is $d_j$ and the $j '$ th column is $\lambda d_j$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ . Then $v$ where $v_j=-\lambda$ and $v_{j'}=1$ and all other entries are $0$ is in the null space of $D$. Now take $T=\{j,j'\}$ and You will see that the null space property is violated for $\Omega=2$ and therefore the matrix does not have the NSP for all $\Omega\geq 2$.

Comment: Thank you! So if two columns of $D$ are correlated, is it not even guaranteed to have the NSP of order 1? Since that depends on $\lambda$.

Comment: Let me think:If $|\lambda|\leq 1$ the the NSP is violated by $T=\{j'\}$ and if $|\lambda|>1$ the NSP is violated by $T=\{j\}$. Yes I think Youŕe right it is even not NSP for $\Omega=1$.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome!